# Getting Exception error when calling WCF Service

Tags: wcf, exception

I have a website (client) consuming the WCF service.

This is what the exception error returns when I run the website with the debugger:

```
        ex        {"Could not find a part of the path 'E:\\ORG_FILES\\Logs\\P_Log.txt'."}      System.Exception {System.ServiceModel.FaultException<System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail>}
```

Inside the web service I have no double \:

String logPath = @"E:/ORG_FILES/Logs/P_Log.txt";

Answer (score 0):

There can be one of the two cause for this error:

1.Path is not correct.
2.Account through which your application is running don't have rights to create directory at path location, like if you are trying to create directory on shared drive with not enough privileges etc.
You can try changing logPath:

```
string  logPath = @"E:\ORG_FILES\Logs\P_Log.txt";
```

or

```
string logPath = "E:\\ORG_FILES\\Logs\\P_Log.txt";
```